# How can I include the PostgreSQL JDBC JAR in my Java project?

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I want to include the PostgreSQL JDBC driver JAR in my project so that it can run on a system that doesn't have it installed. How can I make my class aware of it?

I get this error when I try to run the JAR:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)
at skytracker.data.handler.dataParser.dbConnect(dataParser.java:132)
at skytracker.data.handler.dataParser.main(dataParser.java:25)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
```

Comment: What kind of project? Ant? Maven? Gradle? Eclipse? NetBeans? IntelliJ IDEA? Anyway, all you need to do is make sure the JDBC driver jar file is on the classpath at runtime. As for how you specify that, search the web.

Comment: I'd have a look at [Working with Manifest Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html) to better understand the solution to your problem, how you generate it will depend on the tools you are using

Comment: sorry, I'm using eclipse

Answer (score 0):

For a quick and dirty approach:

1. Copy the jdbc driver jar into your project (I'd create a lib folder and put it inside
2. On the project, select Build path -> Configure build path -> Libraries tab
3. Click on Add JARS..., find your driver lib and add it.

After that, the jdbc driver is on the classpath for the eclipse project and you can use its classes. Note that this will only work *within* eclipse.